# How do I transform data that is in arrays

Tags: powerbi, transform, powerquery

Need assistance with transforming data in order to create relationship between the fact table and dimension table.

The fact table contains requests from customers and these requests are labeled with tags.
Tags column contains string arrays and I need to transform them so that a relationship between fact table TICKET and dimension table TAGS can be created.

Foreign key column in fact table:

[image]

Primary key columnin dimension table:

[image]

Is there a way to transform TICKET.tags in Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery, you will need to split your `tags` column in your `TICKETS` fact table, so that each one will have it's own row.

- Right-click on the `tags` column header and select `Split Column` > `By delimiter`.
- In the window that pops-up, select the needed delimiter (space?), and then expand `Advanced options` and ensure you select `Split into Rows`

Now you can create a relationship between dimension and fact table.

If you don't want to have multiple rows for the same ID in your Facts table, then you can consider having a separate Ticket Tags fact table. For this, duplicate your fact table query, remove all the columns apart from `id` and `tags`, perform the same steps described above.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but this will create duplicates in the fact table which I want to avvoid.

Comment: Updated answer above with creating a separate Ticket Tags fact table.